# Hiding classes by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html

I made a script that when I click on the container it hides a list. However, what I have been trying to do is that the list should hide when clicking *outside* the container and not *inside*. I have been looking for answers but nothing really worked for me as I use classes. Does someone know a solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Hiding the list</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hiding the list</h1>
<div class="list">Hide the list by clicking outside
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
</div>

<div class="list">Hide the list by clicking outside
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
    .list {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    li {

    }
</style>
<script>
    function hide_list() {
        var children = this.children;

        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            children[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    document.querySelectorAll(".list").forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("click", hide_list);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. List items must be children of a list.

Comment: It's also invalid to have content outside the head or body elements. (I've removed those when tidying up your demo.)

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) shows how to do it with jQuery. Converting it to vanilla JS should be straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: @isherwood Please don't ever modify the code of a question that isn't yours. Now the code does not give a true representation of what the OP is working with and therefore even with the main problem solved, other problems may still persist.

Comment: Barmar & isherwood Well the thing is I actually try to avoid using jQuery not because I dont like it but because I have basically no knowledge of it. I have looked up for answers which support classes and JavaScript Vanilla but havent found one with this description

Comment: Please clarify what "outside the list" means to you? Where exactly is someone supposed to click in order to hide, say the second list?

Comment: @ScottMarcus, what change do you claim was problematic? All I did is format. It was logically and functionally identical (and much easier to see).

Comment: @ScottMarcus the main idea is that the person should click wherever he wants except at the container (class ="list") With the first click it should remove the first list, with the second click it should remove the second list. So basically it should work like my script with the only difference that the function runs when the click is outside of the container.

Comment: The question I linked has many answers on it, including some without jQuery involvement. It answers your question, if indirectly. You need to pick what elements to watch.

Comment: you can always add a sibling div which can cover the entire background with positioning, then make that click event on the background div.

Comment: @DavidGrosh well this is an idea that I am able to realize! But the question is -> Would it be still clean code to do that?

Comment: as long as it's readable that that extra div is intended as a background to be clicked on, I would not see any issues with that.

Comment: @isherwood I have looked up the answers and while yes there is one which provides the answer I am looking for, I am not a big fan of assigning every element a different attribute value. But still thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't think that's what's proposed. You just need an event handler on an outer element, even if it's the document. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/1264804.

Comment: alright well I will check that out thank you very much!